# Error in rstanarm with beta regression using stan_glmer

Tags: bayesian, stan

After fitting a `stan_glmer()` or `stan_glm()` functions with `mcgv::betar` as a family, I get an error when I try to call `posterior_predict` on it. R says:

> Error in exp(eta) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

A minimal example:

```
library(rstanarm)
library(loo)
library(mgcv)

a <- rnorm(100, 0.5, 0.1)
b <- a+rnorm(100, 0.6, 0.01)
d <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)

fit <- stan_glm(a ~ b,
               data = d,
               family=betar,
               chains = 10,
               seed = 1)

posterior_predict(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/rstanarm-mgcv-betar-family/2947/4 . It is a bug in rstanarm.